# Expand a column entry and adding values from one or more rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with entries that have the same meaning, I'd like to get them in the same row(and column).
My mock df:

```
my = pd.DataFrame(
{'fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pomme', 'aeble', 'Banan', 'Orange', 'Apelsin'],
'bites': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

and what I would like it to be:

[image]

The closest I've gotten is

```
my.loc['Apple'] +=my.loc['Pomme'] += my.loc['aeble']
```

But I am wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: How get translation in your code?

Comment: The data is messy and I guess I just rely on my own language skills (fortunately the languages present in this df  is mostly languages I know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had some `dict` mapping all `fruit` values to one language, you could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with agg functions `join` and `sum`:

```
d = {'Apple': 'Apple',
     'Banana': 'Banana',
     'Pomme': 'Apple',
     'aeble': 'Apple',
     'Banan': 'Banana',
     'Orange': 'Orange',
     'Apelsin': 'Orange'
    }

my.groupby(my['fruit'].map(d)).agg({'fruit': lambda x: ', '.join(x),
                                    'bites': 'sum'})
```

[out]

```
                      fruit  bites
fruit                             
Apple   Apple, Pomme, aeble      5
Banana        Banana, Banan      4
Orange      Orange, Apelsin      7
```

---

One way to help generate you're mapping `dict` could be to use the [`googletrans`](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) package:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

d = {x.origin: x.text for x in translator.translate(my['fruit'].unique().tolist())}
```

[out]

```
{'Apple': 'Apple',
 'Banana': 'Banana',
 'Pomme': 'Apple',
 'aeble': 'aeble',
 'Banan': 'Banana',
 'Orange': 'Orange',
 'Apelsin': 'Orange'}
```

As you can see, it's not perfect, but will give you a head-start instead of creating entirely manually.

Comment: would this also work if I have entries that are single i e if there was a row with 'pear' and no other entry that represent pear. or do I have to enter each row even if it's the only one of it's kind?

Comment: Yes, single entries should still show up as their own groups

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to create a third column to identify your fruit and then do a groupby :

```
my = pd.DataFrame(
{'fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pomme', 'aeble', 'Banan', 'Orange', 'Apelsin'],
'bites': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

#Create new column
my['Type Fruit'] = ['Apple', 'Bannana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Bannana', 'Orange', 'Orange']
# Group by fruit type
fruit_type = my.groupby(['Type Fruit'])['bites'].agg('sum')

In [1] : print(fruit_type )
Out[1] : Type Fruit
Apple      5
Bannana    4
Orange     7
```

---

The idea of @Chris to use google translate could also be used in this method to create the third column :

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

my['Type Fruit'] = [x.text for x in translator.translate(my['fruit'].unique().tolist())]

# Group by fruit type
fruit_type = my.groupby(['Type Fruit'])['bites'].agg('sum')
```